# Display a message when passwords don't match - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating a form in Angular,
I added a confirm-password field, and I want to display a message when the passwords do not match.
I have tried many different approaches - but it doesn't work. I added a message in the console and it worked properly.
Can someone please help me with this?
Thanks in advance.

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <div class="form-group flex-container">

        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input formControlName="password" id="password" 
               type="password" class="form-control">
        <div *ngIf="password?.touched && password?.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">Password is required</div>

        <label for="confirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
    <input formControlName="confirmPassword" id="confirmPassword" type="password" class="form-control">
    <div *ngIf="confirmPassword?.touched && confirmPassword?.invalid" class="alert alert-danger">Please verify your password.</div>
   <div *ngIf="form.hasError('confirmPassword', 'validate')" class="alert alert-danger">Passwords do not match.</div>

    <button id="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">אישור</button>

</form>
```

**TypeScript**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { PasswordValidators } from './password.validators';

@Component({
  selector: 'customer-registration',
  templateUrl: './customer-registration.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./customer-registration.component.css']
})

export class CustomerRegistrationComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, PasswordValidators.validate])
  });


  ngOnInit() {
    this.form.setValidators(PasswordValidators.validate);
  }


  get password() {
    return this.form.get('password');
  }

  get confirmPassword() {
    return this.form.get('confirmPassword');
  }
```

```
import { AbstractControl, ValidationErrors, FormGroup, ValidatorFn } from '@angular/forms';

export class PasswordValidators {
  static validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    const password = control.get('password')?.value;
    const confirmPassword = control.get('confirmPassword')?.value;

    if (password !== confirmPassword) {
      console.log("passwords do not match");
      return { confirmPassword: true };
      
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because you have your validation on a single FormControl element, but you are attempting to validate multiple FormControls. Your validator function is only receiving the `confirmPassword` FormControl, not the other controls in the form. Since you already have the FormControls in a FormGroup, you can add a validator function to the FormGroup. This function should accept an AbstractControl (which will be the FormGroup) and can return the value as needed. It looks like your existing validator function should already do this.

```
export class CustomerRegistrationComponent {
  form = new FormGroup({
    password: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
    confirmPassword: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
  }, {validator: PasswordValidators.validate});

...
}
```